# Change from a Student Status to a Tourist status in Schengen Zone

Tags: schengen, europe, ukrainian-citizens

My situation is as follows: I am a Ukrainian citizen and have a one-year Italian residence permit for the purpose of studying that is valid until June 16. I am supposed to leave the Schengen zone on June 19. My passport allows me to stay 90/180 days in Schengen. I wanted to ask:

1. Can I stay in Schengen after my permit expires, having the Ukrainian passport, without the need to leave the Schengen zone and reenter?
2. In the following scenario: My permit is valid until June 16, but I leave Italy for Croatia (which is part of the EU but is not part of the Schengen Zone) on June 1 and then, re-enter on the very same day with my passport only without showing my permit anymore. Would my student status change to tourist status in this situation?

Comment: What you are going to do after your residence permit expires in Europe? Tourism?

Comment: yes, I will be travelling